# C# get first row from a dynamic table

Tags: c#, .net, automation

I have created this method to get data from a dynamic table. However, I want to just get the top row each time I call this method. I am unable to find a solution

Basically in the below code, I want to return tablerow[0] of the result

```
    public static Dictionary<string, IWebElement> GetlatestResults(String GridPath, String GridPathHeader)
        {
            var Result = new Dictionary<string, IWebElement>();
           
            var workflowtable = DriverContext.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(GridPath));
            IList<IWebElement> tableRow = workflowtable.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));

            var workflowTableHeader = DriverContext.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(GridPathHeader));
            IList<IWebElement> colElements = workflowTableHeader.FindElements(By.TagName("th"));
            
            //int rowIndex = 0;
            foreach (var row in tableRow)
            {
                int headerValueIndex = 0;
                IList<IWebElement> rowValues = row.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));

                foreach (var rowValue in rowValues)
                {
                  
                    Result.Add(colElements[headerValueIndex].Text, rowValue);

                    headerValueIndex++;
                }

               //rowIndex++;
            };

            return Result;
        }
```

Comment: IWebElement row0 = tableRow[0];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var row = tableRow.First();
int headerValueIndex = 0;
IList<IWebElement> rowValues = row.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));

foreach (var rowValue in rowValues)
{
                  
     Result.Add(colElements[headerValueIndex].Text, rowValue);

     headerValueIndex++;
 }
```

Skip the `foreach` altogether.